# xml sendo gerado com encoding="utf-16"

Tags: c#

Estou com problema ao serializar um xml, o mesmo está sendo gerado com `encoding="utf-16"`.

Mas o `xsd` está com `encoding="utf-8"`, como faço para ele ser gerado com `utf-8`?

```
var xml = string.Empty;
var serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Consulta));
using (var strignWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(strignWriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
    {
        serialize.Serialize(xmlWriter, xmlConsulta);
        xml = strignWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não Entendi, ele ficou assim:

Comment: Como é a estrutura da classe `consulta` e o valor que está atribuindo a `xmlConsulta`?

Comment: Veja isso http://www.csharp411.com/how-to-force-xmlwriter-or-xmltextwriter-to-use-encoding-other-than-utf-16/

Comment: opa, obrigado conseguir com o link acima.

Comment: Editei a resposta, apresentando essa solução. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece por conta do `StringWriter` que usa como padrão o Enconding UTF-16.
Uma é solução fazer a sua própria implementação, herdando do StringWriter e forçando a utilização do UTF-8

```
public class StringWriterWithEncoding : StringWriter 
{ 
    public StringWriterWithEncoding( StringBuilder sb, Encoding encoding ) 
        : base( sb ) 
    { 
        this.m_Encoding = encoding; 
    } 
    private readonly Encoding m_Encoding; 
    public override Encoding Encoding 
    { 
        get
        { 
            return this.m_Encoding; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

E depois faça a alteração no seu código para trabalhar com essa implementação.

```
string xml = string.Empty;
var serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Consulta));

using (var strignWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding(new StringBuilder(),UTF8Encoding.UTF8))
{       
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(strignWriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
    {
        serialize.Serialize(xmlWriter, xmlConsulta);
        xml = strignWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

[Fonte](http://www.csharp411.com/how-to-force-xmlwriter-or-xmltextwriter-to-use-encoding-other-than-utf-16/)

Comment: boa tarde, tentei mas ainda tá saindo como utf16.